# Where could be the problem when one faces exception "No value given for one or more required parameter" OleDb Exeption

Tags: ms-access, oledb

```
        string query = "INSERT INTO EmployeeTable (" +
"empName, CNIC, FatherName, FatherCNIC, Address, Contact, Email, Gender, DOB, PNo, Grade, Trade, Staff, EmployeeType, Residense" +
") VALUES (" +
" @empName, @CNIC,@fatherName,@fatherCNIC, @address, @contact, @email, @gender, @DOB, @Pno, @grade, @trade, @staff, @employeeType, @residense" +
")";
```

It throws exception

> "No value given for one or more required parameter"

when the below statement is executed

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();`

Comment: Are you certain every variable has data? Add tag for language. Show code that declares and sets parameters.

Comment: You have not added any parameters to the command.  Look into Command.Parameters.Add( "parameterName", data/type, valueBeingInsertedOrUpdated )

Comment: I agree with @June7 - you don't show any code and appear to not even tried basic troubleshooting. Debug contents of your string query - and copy/paste into a SQL window to see which parameter is missing